# Pipe stdout and stderr through ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, pipe

Consider the following example:

```
{ echo 1 | tee /dev/stderr 2> >(sed -e 's|1|err|' >&2) 1> >(sed -e 's|1|out|') ; }
```

which prints

```
out
err
```

Note that out `out` is printed on `stdout` and `err` on `stderr`.

**Question**: How to do this remotely via `ssh`?
More precisely, how to run

```
ssh host 'echo 1 | tee /dev/stderr SOME_MAGIC_HERE'
```

st. again `out`/`err` pops up on `stdout`/`stderr` (for an appropriate bash magic `SOME_MAGIC_HERE`).

Clearly, the following works:

```
ssh host 'echo 1 | tee /dev/stderr' 2> >(sed -e 's|1|err|' >&2) 1> >(sed -e 's|1|out|')
```

But that executes `sed` locally, and I'd rather want to do that remotely on `host`.

Comment: What is it that you want. Do you wish that `server:/dev/stderr` is printed to `host:/dev/stderr`?

Comment: Exactly. After `ssh host ...` I want two messages, one on each `/dev/std{err,out}`.

Comment: Please be aware that even in the current command, everything is printed on `/dev/stdout`. You can test this by adding `2>/dev/null` behind it.

Comment: That's not the case for me. I'm testing with `2>/dev/null` using `GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release`.

Comment: type the following : `{ echo 1 | tee /dev/stderr 2> >(sed -e "s|1|err|") 1> >(sed -e "s|1|out|") ; } >/dev/null` and `{ echo 1 | tee /dev/stderr 2> >(sed -e "s|1|err|") 1> >(sed -e "s|1|out|") ; } 2>/dev/null`. The problem is that you need to place things between `{... ; }` because of the redirections.

Comment: I see, you are right. Thanks for pointing this out. Do you know how to massage both streams then?

Comment: sorry I don't get it from this comment. But I'd happily accept it as an answer, since this probably also resumes my issues via `ssh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**after the update:**

```
ssh host 'echo 1 | tee >(cat - | sed -e "s|1|err|" >&2) | sed -e "s|1|out|"'
out
err
```

The idea is to use <pipes> `|` for processing `/dev/stdout` and use process substitution in combination with `tee` to create the `/dev/stderr` part.

Now it works as expected:

```
$ ssh host 'echo 1 | tee >(cat - | sed -e "s|1|err|" >&2) | sed -e "s|1|out|"' > /dev/null
err
$ ssh host 'echo 1 | tee >(cat - | sed -e "s|1|err|" >&2) | sed -e "s|1|out|"' 2> /dev/null
out
```

**original answer:**

The following command executes by changing your <single quotes> into <double quotes> :

```
ssh host 'echo 1 | tee /dev/stderr 2> >(sed -e "s|1|err|") 1> >(sed -e "s|1|out|")'
```

but this has everything in `/dev/stdout`. Example:

```
$ ssh host 'echo 1 | tee /dev/stderr 2> >(sed -e "s|1|err|") 1> >(sed -e "s|1|out|")' > /dev/null
$ ssh host 'echo 1 | tee /dev/stderr 2> >(sed -e "s|1|err|") 1> >(sed -e "s|1|out|")' 2> /dev/null
out
err
```

and this is exactly what your original command does on the host system:

```
{ echo 1 | tee /dev/stderr 2> >(sed -e "s|1|err|") 1> >(sed -e "s|1|out|") ; } >/dev/null
{ echo 1 | tee /dev/stderr 2> >(sed -e "s|1|err|") 1> >(sed -e "s|1|out|") ; } 2>/dev/null
out
err
```

The `ssh` program normally handles the passing of `/dev/stdout`,`/dev/stderr` and `/dev/stdin` correctly:

```
$ ssh host "echo 1; echo 2 > /dev/stderr" > /dev/null
2
$ ssh host "echo 1; echo 2 > /dev/stderr" 2> /dev/null
1
```

Comment: Thats all pretty well and correct. But how do you "pipe" `echo 1 | tee /dev/stderr` through different `sed`s, while preserving stdout/stderr?

Comment: Question updated, since sadly I can't make a solution for my orginial `ssh` issue out of your answer.